# I want to use the math.round function in a jquery file but I do not know where to place it to arrive at the wanted result

Tags: jquery, calculator, decimalformat

I am currently trying to make a calculator in jquery, and i managed to do a couple of things but I encounted some issues and need some help. 
I want to place a math. round function to my code to make the division result more pleasant-looking but do not know exactly where.  I tried with .toFixed but i do not like that for example if I have the operation 5/2, the result will be 2,500 and i want it to look like 2.5. Am I adressing the wrong var? I am lost. Here is  the code:

```
$operators.click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var currValue = $(this).text();
    var currOperand = parseFloat($display.text());
    if (currValue != 'CE') {
        if (operation != null && !afterOperation) {
            switch (operation) {
                case '+':
                    $display.text(operand + currOperand);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    $display.text(operand - currOperand);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    $display.text(operand * currOperand);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    if (currOperand != 0) {
                        $display.text((operand / currOperand).toFixed(3));
                    } else {
                        alert("ERROR");
                        reset();
                    }
                    break;
```

Highly appreciate the help

Comment: What you try to do is not "rounding", that would actually change the results value which you do not want to do in a calculator application. Instead you are trying to format the output according to your visual wishes. you cannot do that with a rounding function. If you take a look into the relevant line you can sport the current formatting: `.toFixed(3)` which basically means: "show with 4 digits after the decimal point". You might want to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Number` in `division` case:

```
$display.text(Number((operand / currOperand).toFixed(3)));
```

This will first convert the string to `Number`.

**Another way**

You can also use `parseFloat`:

```
parseFloat((5 / 2).toFixed(3))
```

Comment: Why 2 decimal places? And what does rounding help in the above example?

Comment: That depends on the situation, I'd say. And it does a) not comply with the requested example and b) change the code the OP has implemented so far without reason.

Comment: This is a completely different answer now. You should explain the _why_, especially why you do _not_ use the rounding function as requested by the OP. And a side note: when using the `Number()` function, then the `.tiFixed(3)` does not really make any sense any more, does it? Also you want to modify the explanation below once more, there is no string to be converted in the first place... Don't get this wrong: not trying to be a pain in the ass. But answers should be precise, shouldn't they?

Comment: @arkascha `toFixed` is necessary if you want only 3 decimal digits. And when you use `toFixed` it returns string, so it is required

Comment: Sorry, the OP states in the example that he does _not_ want 3 decimal points. And if so, why do you insist on 2 decimal places again in your alternative approach, using the `parseFloat()` function?

Comment: @arkascha Habit! Updated.

Comment: Oh, and sorry about my comment to the "conversion" above, that clearly was wrong on my side. Sorry for that.

Comment: I added the Number and it the result was the one I wanted. Many, many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function (`getResult()`) to compare the result of division to that of `.toFixed()` and return the most appropriate representation like so:

```js
function getResult( a, b ) {
    var c = a/b, //numeric
        d = c.toFixed(3); //string
    return c == d ? c : d;
}

$('pre > span[data-a]').each(function() {
    $(this).next().text( getResult( $(this).data('a'), $(this).data('b') ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
<span data-a="5" data-b="2">5/2 = </span><span></span>
<span data-a="5" data-b="3">5/3 = </span><span></span>
<span data-a="4" data-b="3">4/3 = </span><span></span>
</pre>
```

Comment: Wow, you really know code. Thank you so much for the reply but I think your method is rather advanced for my level. I just began 3 days ago and I also want to make sure I understand what I am doing. When I learn more stuff I will def return to your answer and try your version to make my code more efficient and clean. The $display.text(Number((operand / currOperand).toFixed(3))); as proposed by user above seemed to do the trick for now. Thanks again